# jQuery select child of closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to be able to select the div level2 parent from the child level4 div. My application does not has such classes, otherwise I'd just select level2 :)

```
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <div class="level3">
      <div class="level4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level2"> <!-- this is hidden -->
    <div class="level3">
      <div id="start" class="level4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I start with `$('#start')` and search for the first parent which is visible, but I'm not seeing a way to return the child of that parent. Searching for `$('#start')` inside the parent seems very wasteful as I start with a sub child to begin with.

```
$('#start').closest(':visible') // returns level1
$('#start').closest(':visible').first() // returns the first level2. I can't just use second because the number of level2s can change.
$('#start').closest(':visible').children().each(function(){ /* do some search to check it contains `$('#start')` }) // seems very wasteful.
```

Another way to look at what I'm trying to say would be; start in the middle, find the outside (the visible element), and move one element in.

Comment: No, I want the child of in this case level1, but I want the one that contains `id="start"`. Also, those classes don't exist, so I can't search by class at all, they are only there to help explain the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:-

```
$('#start').parentsUntil(':visible').last();
```

This will give you all hidden parent div's until its visible parent and last() wil give the outermost parent which is hidden. last is not a selector on position it is the last() in the collection.

Comment: That also won't necessarily give him an ancestor of the original element

Comment: Sure. The number and order of the nested elements can change so selecting based on index or position is not dependable. He needs to be able to find whichever ancestor div is a direct descendant of the first visible ancestor.

Comment: @ogc-nick  By the way last is not position here last is the last one in the collection of the match. which means the outermost one.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I need. It worked on my initial test, and in your jsfiddle. And thanks for that clarification of last, it was making me a little skeptical. I'll finish testing this, and then accept it

Comment: @Graham Sure. Thats why i updated my answer with more clarification because guess :@ogc-nick got confused with :last selector on the element and  last() on the collection.

Comment: @ogc-nick probably i didn't answer completely and hence the confusion.. :)  I updated it after your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
$('#start').closest(':visible').children().has('#start');
```

[See fiddle for example.](http://jsfiddle.net/QBgaY/)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I misread your code, thanks for the fiddle.  Up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('#start').closest(':visible').children().filter(':first-child')
```

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is also good for selecting pretty much anything.

Comment: That won't necessarily give him an ancestor of the original element

Comment: is that what he wants? the question isn't very clear at all. actually, i don't see the OP state anywhere which element they DO want to select.

Comment: You are correct it isn't clear. But he does say it in the last line of his 3 code example in the comment.

Comment: then his question makes no sense at all. if he wants to select the element with `id="start"`, all he needs to do is write `$('#start')`. what's the point of selecting any parents in the first place?

Comment: He needs to be able to find whichever ancestor div of `$('#start')` is a direct descendant of the first visible ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the classes don't exist...why not add them?  It would make thinks much easier to find.  The class names don't need to have actual styles associated.

```
var allLevel4 = $('#start').closest(':visible').find('.level4');
var firstLevel4 = $('#start').closest(':visible').find('.level4')[0];
var secondLevel4 = $('#start').closest(':visible').find('.level4')[1]; //also, #start
```

Comment: I'm trying to build a universal piece of code, adding the classes would make it easier, but then I'd have to remember to do so for all of my projects. I like the idea of it "just working" without having to bloat the html

Comment: Questions states that there can be any number of  nested elements so selecting them by index won't get him the result he needs.

Comment: Graham, could you please clarify your question?  Show the code that you're actually trying to work with, without the imaginary class names, and state exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  We'll be able to give you much better answers that way.